# XSL-FO creating Dynamic Table Of Contents

Tags: dynamic, reference, xsl-fo, tableofcontents

How we can create a table of contents page dynamically in XSL-FO?

Answer (score 5):

What I've done in the past is use `<fo:page-number-citation>` for each entry in the TOC (Table of Contents). I do the table of contents as an `<fo:table>`.

The `<fo:page-number-citation>` has a `ref-id` attribute that should contain the `id` of the location you're referencing. It should generate the PDF page number where that `id` is located.

For example, if you wanted each `<chapter>` referenced in your TOC, you would use `<fo:page-number-citation>` with a `ref-id` that matched the `id` of where the `<chapter>` was output (like `fo:page-sequence`, `fo:block`, etc.).

Here's an example. I'm basing the `id` attribute on the value of an existing attribute, but you can generate an id if you need to.

Example Chapter XML:

```
<chapter foo="CHAP-1">
...
</chapter>
```

Example entry in the TOC table:

```
<fo:table-cell>
  <fo:block>
    <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="CHAP-1"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Example of outputting the `<chapter>`:

```
<fo:page-sequence id="CHAP-1">
...
</fo:page-sequence>
```

You can also wrap the `fo:page-number-citation` in an `fo:basic-link` to link the page number in the TOC to the actual page.

Comment: But how can i use it if I have more Chapter elments and I have to create the Id's dynamiclly ?

Comment: Is this a Problem that my TOC( Table of Content) is in an other page master than my text?

Comment: @bvb1909 - You should be able to use `generate-id()` to create the IDs. It isn't a problem that the TOC is in a different page master. I would think it would be common for the TOC to be in a different page master.

Comment: I solved my Problem i used the wrong context node :)