# How to preprocess xsl:fo document before pdf generation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsl-fo

consider the following xml:

```
 <book>
    <chapter>
            <title>chapter title 1</title>
        <id>chapterId1</id>
        <content>some content</content> 
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
            <title>chapter title 2</title>
        <id>chapterId2</id>
        <content>some content</content> 
    </chapter>
</book>
```

I want to generate a book with table of contents. So i create the TOC like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="book/chapter">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id" >
                <xsl:attribute name="ref-id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </fo:page-number>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the `ref-id` attribute is overwritten on the fly and replaced by the value of the chapter id.

The problem here is that the referenced id are not yet knwon in the document. Because I use the same `<xsl:attribute>` element to create set the chapter id's on the cahpeter blocks.

```
<fo:block> <!-- the chapter container -->
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="chapter/id" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <fo:block>
      the chapter content.....
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

How do I preprocess my xsl:fo file so that the fo:block elements have the correct ID's already set?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do any preprocessing. Each chapter needs to be processed twice by the XSLT stylesheet: when generating the main content and when generating the TOC. Just make sure that you use the same IDs in both cases.

The following stylesheet illustrates how this can be done (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286464/407651)). It works on your example source document.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/book">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
       <fo:layout-master-set>
          <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" 
                                 page-height="11in">
             <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in"/>
          </fo:simple-page-master>
       </fo:layout-master-set>
       <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
         <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <!-- Call the template that generates the TOC -->
           <xsl:call-template name="genTOC"/>
         </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
        <!-- Then output the main content -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="genTOC">
    <fo:block break-before='page'>
      <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold">TABLE OF CONTENTS</fo:block>
      <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
        <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::chapter) + 1" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />
            <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{id}" />
        </fo:block>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title|content">
    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page" id="{id}">
       <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```